# Thymeleaf Model attribute not present

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

**Situation**

I am using SpringBoot application with the Thymeleaf templating engine. I posted a simplified version of the code that is being involved. A controller is adding an attribute to the Model object and then returning DeferredResult. At the end the attributes form the model are used in the Thymeleaf template to render them on the page.

**Problem**

I know if the object would not be added to the model it would throw an exception in the Thymeleaf template, because of the missing guard block or th:if. But I am setting initialized object before any code is being executed. I am also logging the value of the model for debugging purposes and its always present after the calculation. So model with appropriate key is set but at the point of rendering thymeleaf the key in model returns null value. This only happens under a heavy load. In the production system or when simulating load with more than 30 concurrent requests.

It happens 1~2 times in a 100 requests.

I store multiple objects, in the model. They are randomly null.

I also tried logging all the values with following code. All other data seems to be fine and present, only single object in the case below missing one is "model_key".

```
<table id="model-attributes">
  <tr th:each="var : ${#vars}">
    <td th:text="${var.key}"></td>
    <td th:text="${var.value}"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Question**

Did anyone else experienced similar issues. Can it be the Thymeleaf caching issue?

**Code**

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/path") 
public DeferredResult<String> processRequest(Model model) throws Exception {

  // To make sure the model is not null add it already before any computation
  model.addAttribute("model_key", new ModelValue());
  ModelValue modelValue = calculateModel();

  // For debugging purposes
  log("Model Value " + modelValue);

  // Add the actual model
  if(modelValue != null) {
    model.addAttribute("model_key", modelValue);
  } else {
    log.error("Model was empty");
  }
  deferredResult.setResult("template_name");
}
```

**Thymeleaf template**

```
<p th:text="${model_key.id}">
```

**Exception log**

```
2018-11-12T07:45:28.691Z ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] [http-nio-8080-exec-6] : Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null    
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:220)
org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
```

Comment: I don't think you should be using  `DeferredResult<String>` with a model attribute like you are.  What is the reason you're doing it like that?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you able to fix this?